# Load Pyqt5 project by .py file

Tags: pyqt5

I have compiled my user interface file (.ui file) to python file via pyuic tools,
My question is should I load the project by the .py file?
if yes. how to do that?.
Besides, after I deploy the project can users access the .py or even the .ui file?
Below code is for loading my ui file:

```
    class GUI(QMainWindow): #Base Class 
        def __init__(self): 
            super(GUI,self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi("Char.ui", self)
    if __name__ == "__main__": # To Loop the App 
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = GUI()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is very confusing. First of all, assuming that by "I have converted my ui file to .py" you mean that you used the pyuic tool, then it's completely useless, since in your code you're still using the ui file. Then, it's unclear what you mean with the second phrase.

Comment: yes i mean i used pyuic tool,  i ask if i should use the py file to load the project instead ui, and how to do that

Comment: The choice is completely up to you. I usually prefer using ui files, as using pyuic files implies that you **must** remember to *always* update the generated files whenever you edit them in designer. Using pyuic classes allows some level of extensibility, though, but doing that is usually for quite skilled and experienced users, so that usually makes the choice just a matter of preference and habit. Read how to properly use the generated files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can modify like this

```
# xx_ui is the converted .py file of your .ui file
form xx_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class GUI(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow): #Base Class 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(GUI,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # uic.loadUi("Char.ui", self)
```

2. After compiling into .exe file, you cannot directly see the .py and .ui files

Comment: it doesn't work , AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'frame_7 , this frame is exist i checked and it was work before i apply your changes

Comment: You're missing `self.setupUi(self)`, otherwise the multiple inheritance is useless, since that function is the only things that actually sets up the UI.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the method of setting the ui, I have modified it. Thinks @musicamante